# Dynamic $refs can't be referenced in Javascript if a function is used on them [VUE]

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am dynamically generating $ref names using a template for-loop.

If I console log a specific item in the for-loop (see example), it can be reached. However when I take that same reference and call a function on it like focus() or scrollToView(), the console becomes woefully confused and throws an error:

```
vue.js:1743 TypeError: this.$refs.element2.focus is not a function
```

So just to be clear:

```
console.log(this.$refs['element2']); <-- WORKS!
this.$refs['element2'].focus(); <-- DOESNT WORK :(
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3xj7afgh/238/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your template from the fiddle:

```vue
<div v-for="(result, index) in data" :key="index">
  <input type="text" type="file" :ref="'element' + result.id" />
</div>
```

The following excerpt from the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) applies in this situation:

> When used on elements/components with `v-for`, the registered reference will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances.

So you'd need to do this:

```
this.$refs['element2'][0].focus()
```

Mixing dynamic refs and `v-for` can get messy, as you can see.

Alternatively you can use a static ref to achieve the same sort of thing:

```vue
<div v-for="(result, index) in data" :key="index">
  <input type="text" type="file" ref="elements" />
</div>
```

```js
// Index 1 is the second element in the DOM
this.$refs.elements[1].focus()
```